# Configure Varnish 4 multiple domains different ports

Tags: varnish

I got this to load both the websites, however I am unable to log into both wordpress websites.

```
backend websiteone {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "7070";
}
backend websitetwo {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "2082";
}
    sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host ~ "^(.*\.)?websiteone\.com$") {
    set req.backend_hint = websiteone;
    return (hash);
}
    if (req.http.host ~ "^(.*\.)?websitetwo\.com$") {
    set req.backend_hint = websitetwo;
    return (hash);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you describe the issue with more details? Are you seeing both websites? not at all? what fails exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to resolve this issue:

## ```
mkdir /etc/varnish/sites-enabled
```

## ```
cd /etc/varnish/sites-enabled
```

## ```
nano siteone.com.vcl
```

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "siteone.com") {
        if (req.url ~ "/(cart|my-account|checkout|addons|/?add-to-cart=)") {
        return (pass);
        }
    }
}
```

## ```
nano sitetwo.com.vcl
```

```
backend sitetwo {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "2082";
}

sub vcl_recv {
       if (req.http.host == "sitetwo.com") {
           set req.backend_hint = sitetwo;
    }
}
```

Then I had to edit /etc/varnish/default.vcl

## ```
cd /etc/varnish/
```

## ```
nano default.vcl
```

The backend is configured for sitetwo as you can see above, but the backend for siteone is configured in default.vcl so I changed

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "7070";
}
```

And added these two lines to the bottom of default.vcl

```
 include "sites-enabled/siteone.com.vcl";
 include "sites-enabled/sitetwo.com.vcl";
```

Everything seems to be working correctly now! And if I have to add any more sites all I have to do is create sitetree.com.vcl in /sites-enabled folder and paste

```
backend sitethree {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "port number";
}

sub vcl_recv {
       if (req.http.host == "sitethree.com") {
           set req.backend_hint = sitethree;
    }
}
```

Note: *Siteone is running an ecommerce site so if you are not running a store then you should just be able to use the following in siteone.com.vcl*

```
sub vcl_recv {
       if (req.http.host == "siteone.com") {
           set req.backend_hint = siteone;
    }
}
```